# Retrieving autoincrement column after insert in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert, auto-increment

I have a table in SQLite3 with the following schema:

```
create table threads(
  id            integer primary key autoincrement,
  submitter     text,
  body          text,
  title         text,
  subtime       int -- Unix time
);
```

I'm inserting rows like this:

```
insert into threads (title, body, subtime, submitter) values
("I like ducks", "Don't you?", 1467664977640, "tom");
```

I'd like to to get the id column after I insert the thread. How can I do this? Ideally I could insert and retrieve the column in the same statement.

Comment: From which language are you accessing the DB?

Comment: I'm using [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) in Go with [mattn's driver](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Result interface](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Result) allows you to access this value without having to execute another query:

```
res, err := db.Exec("INSERT ..."), someParam)
if err != nil {
    println("Exec err:", err.Error())
} else {
    id, err := res.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        println("Error:", err.Error())
    } else {
        println("LastInsertId:", id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that in one statement but immediately after the insert statement you can use the following statement to get the last auto incremented id:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Another way is to use the following statement:

```
select seq from sqlite_sequence where name="threads"
```